# get rows from a table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I Used SQL Server DBMS

I have a requirment, to get rows from a table with dynamic columns

```
select * from TempXmlData
T1  t2  t3  t4
A   B   C   D
```

The T1,T2,T3,T4 columns are dynamic. I create them by xml config.
of Course,The column name is exist in another tables.like this

```
select * from #TempA
--The Result
T1
T2
T3
T4
```

If config have five columns, this table hase five columns, if config only has one column, this table only has one column.

Now I want to get value from `TempXmlData` from this table. I need to 
put value together like `'A','B',‘C’,'D'`. So I need to get the values from every column, the column is unfixed.

If the Columns is fixed, I can use this way to get the value

```
select @Value = T1(columnName) from TempXmlData
```

Comment: Why!? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Business Need,andI have finished .

Comment: What is the column name in `#TempA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db3f3/9)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TempA
    (columnName varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO TempA
    (columnName)
VALUES
    ('T1'),
    ('T2'),
    ('T3'),
    ('T4')
;

CREATE TABLE TempXmlData
    (T1 varchar(1), T2 varchar(1), T3 varchar(1), T4 varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO TempXmlData
    (T1, T2, T3, T4)
VALUES
    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @colTable table(rownum int, columnName varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @colTable SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY columnName), columnName FROM TempA
DECLARE @query varchar(500)
DECLARE @i int, @max int
SET @i = 1
SET @max = (SELECT count(*) FROM @colTable)
SET @query = 'select '
WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
    IF @i > 1 SET @query = @query + ','
    SET @query = @query + (SELECT columnName FROM @colTable WHERE rownum = @i)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SET @query = @query + ' from TempXmlData'
exec(@query)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db3f3/9/0)**:

```
| T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 |
|----|----|----|----|
|  A |  B |  C |  D |
```

Comment: Thanks your Patient answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a dynamic table definition.  Your only options is to create a proc that returns a result set.  Inside the proc you can dynamically build a SQL statement inside the proc by reading the rows from your #TempA table.  See MS documentation on [cursors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) and [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).